# UISwitch is changing state on other cell when scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiswitch

My tableview looks like this

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! Cell
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 200
}
```

And my tableviewcell looks like this

```
class Cell: UITableViewCell {

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

}
```

When I change switch state on any cell and scroll. The switch for another cell periodically have state changed on scroll for other cells. Please help

[image: layout of uiswitch]

Comment: It is because of cell dequeueing. Can you please update you question with data models?

Comment: That's the problem. I created test project to see if my data model causing this issue. But with just these code it is giving me same issue

Comment: Please check my updated [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45857034/1556386)

Comment: Add a boolean flag in your data model (used to load cell data) and save the switch status whenever updated. In your cellForRowAt method, based on the boolean flag set the switch status accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to have data array with state for every switch and in your didSelect method change data model for switch then in cellForRow at get switch state from array and your viewController need to be SwitchControlDelegate

```
class UIViewController:SwitchControlDelegate{

    var array = [Bool](count: 200, repeatedValue:false)

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! Cell
    cell.switchControl.isOn = array[indexPath.row]
    cell.switchDelegate = self
    cell.index = indexPath.row
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 200
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    array[indexPath.row] = !array[indexPath.row]
}

func switchChangeStateWithIndex(index:Int){
    array[index] = !array[index]
}
```

This will change switch state when you click on cell , if you need to change state when change switch control you will need delegate to update data model in viewController

In your cell file:

```
    protocol SwitchControlDelegate: class {
        func switchChangeStateWithIndex(index:Int)
    }

    class Cell: UITableViewCell {

        var index:Int = 0
        weak var switchDelegate: SwitchControlDelegate?
        override func awakeFromNib() {
            super.awakeFromNib()
            // Initialization code
        }

        override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
            super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

            // Configure the view for the selected state
        }

        @IBAction func valueChanged(_ sender: AnyObject) {
             switchDelegate?.switchChangeStateWithIndex(index:index)
        }

}
```

You need to match action value change from your switch control with this function valueChanged , so every time when you change switch state cell need to call func value Changeed

Comment: Hi Svetoslav, I am having same issue with your code. When I scroll, the selected row whose switch is changes. Goes back to unselected state.

Comment: Please see my updated code and if you still has problems then paste me your viewController and cellFile with all IBOutlets and IBActions

Comment: Thanks for new code and will post if it doesn't  work. But could you tell cell.delegate. It shows an error that cell has no delegate method. Please help to fix this issue to test your code

Comment: I managed to fix the issue. Attach screen showing the connection to my question

Comment: You need to match action

Comment: Also, could you please upvote my question. Other people can also get help from it

Answer (score 0):

Handle your switch control properly for each cell in,

```
tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

so that when cell is dequeue, it handles each cell's `switchControl` properly.

**Solution:**
When you change state of switch control for cell, save that `indexPath` somewhere so that when you iterate through this indexPath in  tableview `cellForRowAt indexPath` you set that state of switch again else set default state